# Send a wall post using Jquery's AJAX (Post)

Tags: facebook, jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I'm trying to post a wall message from a local desktop application (I can't use the FB JS SDK).

Here's a a snippet of my code

```
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed";
var params = "access_token=" + token + "&message=" + encodeURI(text);

 $.ajax({
           crossDomain: true,
           data: params,
           dataType: "jsonp",
           url: url,
           type: 'POST',
           success: function (data) {
                   if (callback) {
                       var isOK = (data && data.id && !data.error);
                       callback(isOK, data);
                   }
               },
           error: function (data, e1, e2) {

                   }
  });
```

The request ignores the message parameter.
I receive a list of feeds as it were a GET request.

I've tried to set the parameters as map but it didn't help.
BTW - when using CURL (in C++) i manage to post the data correctly.

Any ideas why it ignores the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the "params" into the data element like so:

```
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed";


 $.ajax({
           crossDomain: true,
           data: { access_token: token, message: text  },
           dataType: "jsonp",
           url: url,
           type: 'POST',
           success: function (data) {
                   if (callback) {
                       var isOK = (data && data.id && !data.error);
                       callback(isOK, data);
                   }
               },
           error: function (data, e1, e2) {

                   }
  });
```

Let jQuery encode the parameters from there.

Answer (score 0):

Below worked fine in Jquery 1.6.4 + jquery.mobile-1.0rc2 by setting $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; in mobileinit bind

```
$.ajax( {                                    
    url : "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed",
    type : "POST",
    data : "access_token=" + your_access_token + "&message=my first wall post",
    cache : false,
    success : function(res) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
           alert("Couldn't Publish Data");
        } else {
           alert("Message successfully posted to your wall");
        }
    },
    error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```